# greenDAO generator gives console error that doesn't make sense

Tags: android, greendao

I'm pretty new to Android development in general, and I've never even used greenDAO. But after spending a lot of time working on my generator class (Where I model my entities), I was finally able to produce something that looked similar to the example given on GitHub.

```
import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator;
import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Entity;
import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Property;
import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Schema;
import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.ToMany;


public class simbalDAOgen {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Schema schema = new Schema(1, "com.bkp.simbal"); //Schema(Int version, String package name)
    addCBTrans(schema); //Add the entities to the schema
    new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "../Simbal/src-gen", "../Simbal/src-test"); //Generate DAO files
}

private static void addCBTrans(Schema schema){
    Entity checkbook = schema.addEntity("Checkbook");
    checkbook.addIdProperty();
    checkbook.addStringProperty("name").notNull();
    checkbook.addDateProperty("dateModified");
    checkbook.addStringProperty("balance"); // Use a string property because BigDecimal type should be used for currency

    Entity transaction = schema.addEntity("Transaction");
    transaction.setTableName("TRANS"); // "TRANSACTION" is a reserved SQLite keyword
    transaction.addIdProperty();
    transaction.addStringProperty("name");
    transaction.addStringProperty("category");
    Property transDate = transaction.addDateProperty("date").getProperty();
    transaction.addStringProperty("amount"); // Again use string for BigDecimal type
    transaction.addStringProperty("notes");
    Property cbName = transaction.addStringProperty("cb").notNull().getProperty(); //What checkbook the transaction is in

    ToMany cbToTrans = checkbook.addToMany(transaction, cbName); //Actually ties the transactions to their correct checkbooks
    cbToTrans.setName("Transactions");
    cbToTrans.orderAsc(transDate);
}       
}
```

I then ran the code as a java application to generate my DAO files, just like the documentation on greenDAO says to. The files were successfully generated, however I did get this line in the console in Eclipse:

```
Warning to-one property type does not match target key type: ToMany 'Transactions' from Checkbook to Transaction
```

I'm really not sure if I need to be concerned since the files were generated. But what I don't understand is why there's mention of a "to-one" relation when I'm using a "to-many" relation, as can be seen in my code. (There can be many transaction entities in a checkbook entity, and I'm intending to use each checkbook entitys' name to tie the transactions to it.)

Do I need to go back and fix a part of my code? Please ask if I need to clarify anything, and thanks for your time!

Comment: You are right, it's a pretty obscure message. Thank you for both the question and the answer!

Answer (score 7):

After looking at the files generated for me by greenDAO, I've found the solution to my problem. It seems to me that the addToMany() method expects a Long property to be passed to it and I was using a String property. So I changed these two lines in my generator code:

```
Property cbName = transaction.addStringProperty("cb").notNull().getProperty();

ToMany cbToTrans = checkbook.addToMany(transaction, cbName);
```

to this:

```
Property checkbookId = transaction.addLongProperty("checkbookId").notNull().getProperty();

ToMany cbToTrans = checkbook.addToMany(transaction, checkbookId);
```

which solved my problem. I was under the impression I could use any type of property to tie the transactions to the checkbook, so I was trying the use the checkbook name.

Comment: It does need a Long property. GreenDAO (and pretty much any DAO for any framework) resolves 1:n relations by storing the ID of the parent row in a column in every child row. That's your Property checkbookId. 1:1 works similarly, except that the ID can be placed in either or both of the connected tables for the other row. Operating similarly with a String property requires foreign key support, which is not enabled by default in Android SQLite dbs. You can use String as a foreign key, but GreenDAO lacks the ability to automatically resolve these relations and Android SQLite will not enforce it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be GreenDao only accepts type Long as foreign key